# Is it possible to accept credit card payments on a static site?

Tags: paypal, github-pages, payment, credit-card, static-site

I use GitHub pages to host a website. I currently accept payments through paypal.me but would like to add credit card payments, and it looks like I need a server backend to use PayPal's "integration" feature. Is there any way to accept credit card payments on a static site, preferably but not necessarily through PayPal?

Comment: This is in a comment rather than an answer because it's not about Paypal, but Ko-fi does have a decent widget that works fine on static sites, if you wanted to try out a different solution.

Comment: What you have is already sufficient. You don't need a PayPal account to pay a PayPal payment. Just a credit card.

Comment: @user207421 I believe there is no way for a user to pay with a credit card on a static site without logging into PayPal and funding their account first, with the possible exception of the answer below, which is limited to a donate button or recurring subscription.

Comment: @ZacAnger thanks. However, their branding seems a bit unprofessional for my purposes. I wonder if there is a way to heavily customize it.

Comment: @BigMistake I have customers who have managed it.

Comment: @user207421 Do you know what service they used?

Comment: @BigMistake What do you mean by ‘service’?

Comment: @user207421 I meant website credit card processing service providers, such as Stripe, PayPal, etc.

Comment: @BigMistake PayPal Smart Buttons and Donate Buttons. You just paste the generated HTML into your static HTML *et voila.* I've been doing this since about 2006.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited) As of Feb/March 2024, buttons/links/QRs that do *not* require a backend can potentially be generated via the several options at: [https://www.paypal.com/buttons](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=%252Fbuttons%252F) (sign in to see options specific for a particular receiving account type and country)

Separately, a link to send money to a PayPal account can also be generated via https://paypal.me